# get hash code from mp3 file

Tags: mp3, hashcode

how can i get A hash code from mp3 file with this property:

No different between result for same mp3 files with bit rates highest than 8.

Id3 tags do not affect the result.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think two differently encoded bit-rates from the same audio file can be equated by hashing mechanisms. You will need more sophisticated techniques that may not even be deterministic (think heuristic).

While this is a negative answer, maybe there are simpler methods some one here will point you to.
And, they demonstrate my take as incorrect, I am happy to increase my understanding here `:-)`

Comment: i think it is possible ! because  there are programs that when here a music sound, detect the music name ! i tried them whit a song and different bit rates!  the result was same!

Comment: Are you sure, that the program doesn't use ID3 tags ?

Answer (score 0):

Generate an audio fingerprint, tolerant of encoding:

```
  ffmpeg -i input.ogg output.wav
  fpcalc -raw output.wav > fingerprint.txt
```

Details https://musicbrainz.org/doc/AcoustID